# Getting JNLP installs to work on a local machine

Tags: java, jnlp

I have an application that is distributed via JNLP. This works great, except for the few places that do not have a good enough internet connection to download the app (T1 connections).

I am getting them the app by creating a package that can be put on a disk, copied, and have the JNLP file run locally.

The JNLP file now looks like this:

```
    <jnlp spec="7.0+" href="launch.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>EAGLE TEST</title>
        <icon href="img/splash.png" kind="splash"/>
        <icon href="img/icon.png"/>
        <offline-allowed/> 
        <shortcut online="false" install="true">
            <desktop />
            <menu sub-menu="EAGLE"/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <update check="timeout" policy="prompt-run"/>
    <security>fsddf
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
   <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>

<jar href="eagle-client-core.jar" version="2.2.0-b4" main="true"/>
<jar href="biometric-services-commons.jar" version="1.2"/>
<jar href="jackson-annotations.jar" version="2.4.3"/>

 </resources>
 <application-desc main-class="foo.bar.baz.client.Main">
 </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

It looks good. However, when I run the launch.jnlp file I get an exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: (file:/C:/Users/me/path/app/webstart/eagle-client-core.jar?version-id=2.2.0-b4, 2.2.0-b4)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
```

With a wrapped exception of:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\me\path\app\webstart\eagle-client-core.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
```

Now, this indicates that the file can't be found. However, the path

> C:\Users\me\path\app\webstart\eagle-client-core.jar

is the correct path. I have also tried specifying the codebase in the JNLP file as

> file:///C:/Users/me/path/app/webstart/launch.jnlp

I get the same error: Cannot find the file specified.

I have been unable to find out potential causes for JNLP not being able to load a local resource. I have tried with the backslashes as forward ones for windows, and many other variations.

I have used the JaNeLA tool, and it gives the same error, but no indication as to how to resolve it: Problem fetching resource eagle-client-core.jar C:\Users\me\path\app\webstart\eagle-client-core.jar (The System Cannot find the file specified.)

Any insight into what is preventing the system from finding the files would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't hear about serving jnlp files locally, but if you had to because of slow connection, maybe install some http server locally, then copy your application there to the public folder as you usually serve jnlp wide on internet.

Now you can acces it via
    $ javaws localhost/launch.jnlp

Comment: Java documentation says that it should work using a local filesystem, and in my environment the simplest, least complex solution is going to be required.

Comment: Finally it can be done without local webserver. Add codebase to your jnlp
    codebase="file:/path/to/your/jnlp/"
then add the same path to Exception Site List in jcontrol.
That work's for me on java 8u73.

Comment: I've found that adding the codebase and adding to the exception site list does not change anything for me. I've added the following:file:///C:/Users/zmelnic/clientWAR/EAGLE_CLIENT/webstart
file://C:/Users/me/path/app/webstart
file://C:/Users/me/path/app/webstart/launch.jnlp
file://C:\Users\me\path\app\webstart
And none of it changes anything. It appears that the exception site list isn't a problem though, since JavaWS is able to find and load the launch.jnlp file. It chokes at the download after it has read the file.

Comment: My solution worked for me, but I'm on linux. From path c:/users I see you are on Windows. That must be something os speciphic, probably folder delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

codebase is optional now. You can visit the below URL for more info.
[JNLP Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html)

So, you can omit that field in your jnlp and try.